# Are there similar android methods of java getData().getPixels()?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, getpixel

I'm trying to use the following code of java to read image data on android. Since ImageIO is not supported, what are some ways I may use getData().getPixels()?

By changing BufferedImage into Bitmap, I can get all other codes working besides bi.getData().getPixels()?

Any method in the android library I may use to replace it?

In  android Bitmap class:
public void getPixels (int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)

This method supports int[], but not double[]. I'm not familiar with image processing will they be different?

Thank you.

```
    private double[] getImageData(String imageFileName) throws FaceRecError {
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    double[] inputFace = null;
    try{
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFileName));
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        throw new FaceRecError(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    if (bi != null){
    int imageWidth = bi.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = bi.getHeight();
    inputFace = new double[imageWidth * imageHeight];
    bi.getData().getPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight,inputFace);
    }
    return inputFace;
}
```

Comment: getPixels() of bitmap return pixels color

Comment: the method you have mentioned above is available in andriod. it returns an int[] only. if u want it in double[] type cast int[] to double[]

Comment: yes you can typecast to double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is used for getting color of all pixels in Bitmap in android.This return array of color

```
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file path");
    int height=bitmap.getHeight();
    int width=bitmap.getWidth();
    int[] pixel=new int[height*width];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixel, 0, width, 0, width, width, height);
```

So your color will be saved in pixel array. `getPixels()` have many parameter to customize which pixel color you want

**Updated For Casting Integer array to double**

```
public  double[] getDoubleNumbers(int[] numbers) 
//changed double to double[]
{double[] newNumbers = new double[numbers.length]; //changed 99 to numbers.length
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
newNumbers[index] = (double)numbers[index];

return newNumbers;
}
}
```

Comment: will simple casting from integer to double create different in color they represent?

Comment: I think color should not be change as 0 and 0.0000 represent same color.But i will suggest you to not change it double if possible.Should i post how cast in good manner from int to double

Comment: I'm thinking about casting each integer in the array to double. What's the good manner? Thank you